# String manipulation using Regex Substring

Tags: sql, regex, string

I have a problem with a string manipulation where I need to use regex (REGEXP_SUBSTR) to get the result.

I have the following String:

```
Test1:Love,Test2:Joy
```

Now I need to perform a search that will find the value of Test1 using Test2.

So If my Test2 is Joy, it will result to Test 1 = Love.

In sql, I can use "CONTAINS" but it also generates results for Joy2 Joy3 etc. which is not what I want.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Which SQL engine it is?

Comment: Actually, this is by using netsuite saved search

Comment: Can you clarify your problem please? Give a few examples of strings where you have matches and non-matches and explain why one matches while not the others, and put the current output when you use "CONTAINS".

Comment: Why do you want to do this, `String manipulation using Regex Substring`, in SQL? This is not what the language has been designed for, even though it does get extended with certain features from time to time.